# Getting data from multiple tables results with less records

Tags: php, mysql

I have Joomla tables (shown bellow) with some records in it (records are about companies). What I want to achieve is to get all records and group them to new table (I am using PHP for this). Problem is that there is 548 records (companies) and I got 439 records (after grouping).

Does someone knows where's the problem?

Here is database:

[image: Database]

And here is query:

```
SELECT a.itemid as ID, a.title as Name, c.name as Categories, d.data_txt as Description, d.fieldid as FieldID FROM `jos_sobi2_item` as a 
        INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_cat_items_relations` as b ON b.itemid=a.itemid 
        INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_categories` as c ON c.catid = b.catid
        INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data`as d ON a.itemid=d.itemid
```

Comment: Are you sure that in the related table which is joined with `jos_sobi2_item` having the same amount of record or in other words `inner join` will give you only data which is satisfying the join condition.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty jos_sobi2_item got 548 records so I think that my query needs to have 548 records but for some reason it have 439

Comment: @adarshhota I tried with LEFT JOIN but I got 440 records (only 1 more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is inner join is filtering out the records which are not in the related tables but in `jos_sobi2_item`

You may want to do `left join` something as

```
select
a.itemid as ID, 
a.title as Name, 
c.name as Categories, 
d.data_txt as Description, 
d.fieldid as FieldID 
FROM `jos_sobi2_item` as a 
left join `jos_sobi2_cat_items_relations` as b ON b.itemid=a.itemid 
left join `jos_sobi2_categories` as c ON c.catid = b.catid
left join `jos_sobi2_fields_data`as d ON a.itemid=d.itemid
```

Here is an illustration of this

```
create table table1 (t1id int , name varchar(100));
insert into table1 values (1,'aa'),(2,'cc'),(3,'dd'),(4,'ee'),(5,'ff'),(6,'bb'),(7,'gg');

create table table2 (t2id int, description varchar(100));
insert into table2 values (1,'desc1'),(2,'desc2'),(3,'desc3');

create table table3 (t3id int, t1id int , t2id int);
insert into table3 values (1,1,2),(2,3,2),(3,2,2),(4,7,3);

create table table4 (t4id int , t1id int ,fieldid int);
insert into table4 values (1,1,10),(2,3,23),(3,4,34),(4,5,50);

select
t1.t1id,
t1.name,
t2.description,
t4.fieldid
from table1 t1 
left join table3 t3 on t3.t1id = t1.t1id
left join table2 t2 on t2.t2id = t3.t2id
left join table4 t4 on t4.t1id = t1.t1id;

+------+------+-------------+---------+
| t1id | name | description | fieldid |
+------+------+-------------+---------+
|    1 | aa   | desc2       |      10 |
|    2 | cc   | desc2       |    NULL |
|    3 | dd   | desc2       |      23 |
|    4 | ee   | NULL        |      34 |
|    5 | ff   | NULL        |      50 |
|    6 | bb   | NULL        |    NULL |
|    7 | gg   | desc3       |    NULL |
+------+------+-------------+---------+
```

The above example is similar to what you have.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried with left join but I got 1 record more.

Comment: Are you sure the table `jos_sobi2_item` has `548` records ? Do a `select coount(*) from jos_sobi2_item` and see how many records are there. Also double check that you are in the same DB where the query is getting executed. I updated answer with an illustration similar to your DB structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use `INNER`
1. Try a `LEFT JOIN` instead a `INNER JOIN`, and put a condition in `WHERE`

```
SELECT a.itemid as ID, a.title as Name, c.name as Categories, d.data_txt as Description, d.fieldid as FieldID FROM `jos_sobi2_item` as a 
  LEFT JOIN `jos_sobi2_cat_items_relations` as b ON b.itemid=a.itemid 
  LEFT JOIN `jos_sobi2_categories` as c ON c.catid = b.catid
  LEFT JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data`as d ON a.itemid=d.itemid
WHERE b.itemid IS NULL OR c.catid IS NULL OR d.itemid IS NULL
```

2. Look at your results and see where you have nulls, after that you will discover what records from the `jos_sobi2_item` don't have a connection in the other tables.

Or if you want to use `LEFT JOIN` :
1.Run the query:

```
SELECT a.itemid as ID, a.title as Name, c.name as Categories, d.data_txt as Description, d.fieldid as FieldID,
COUNT(b.itemid), COUNT(c.catid), COUNT(d.itemid)
FROM `jos_sobi2_item` as a 
  LEFT JOIN `jos_sobi2_cat_items_relations` as b ON b.itemid=a.itemid 
  LEFT JOIN `jos_sobi2_categories` as c ON c.catid = b.catid
  LEFT JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data`as d ON a.itemid=d.itemid
GROUP BY a.itemid
```

2. Analyze the counts for duplicate records, you can put a condition where count > 1 on every count.